# JQuery mobile UI-scaling in webview

Tags: android, jquery, jquery-mobile

Currently i am working on a web based module in android app.I use Jquery mobile design and import it in the android activity using webview.When i run the activity,the design is displayed but not scaled to the webview,It contains horizontal and vertical  scrolls.I have attached the code along with this post.I need assistance for scaling the activity of jquery mobile design.Thanks in advance!

```
package com.example.updatesuite;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.webkit.WebChromeClient;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;

@SuppressLint("SetJavaScriptEnabled")
public class Gateway extends Activity {
    WebView wv1;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_gateway);
        wv1=(WebView)findViewById(R.id.webView1);
        WebSettings webSettings = wv1.getSettings();
        webSettings.setDefaultFontSize(14);
        wv1.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
        wv1.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
        wv1.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        wv1.getSettings().setSupportZoom(false);
        wv1.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(false);
        wv1.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
        wv1.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
        wv1.loadUrl("http://applicationdownloader.pixub.com/walcliff/index.php");

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.gateway, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

[image: scaling problem in emulator]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I remember correctly then one of the following, or a combination of the two, is causing your problem in Android

```
wv1.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
wv1.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
```

I believe the `UseWideViewPort` tells the WebView to load in desktop mode.

Also, your html pages should have

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no">
```

between the `head` tags.  (With this tag you may not need to modify the WebViewSettings)